# CGAL 2D delaunay triangulation with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: cgal, delaunay

I am new to CGAL, so I do not know where to start.

I want CGAL to calculate a delaunay triangulation of a set of points in 2D. My problem is that there is a class for [nonperiodic systems](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Section_2D_Triangulations_Delaunay) and another one for periodic systems (sorry, can not post more than 2 links), but none for mixed periodic and nonperiodic systems.

Imagine something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwCtv.jpg), which is periodic in x direction.

For your information: The vertices near the upper und lower boundary are connected to vertices far from y=0, but this not particularly relevant to the problem.

Is there any easy way to achieve this or do I need to implement this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D Periodic triangulation package in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) only handle periodicity in the x and y direction (i.e triangulation in the two dimensional flat torus).